# Android Image Upload Service

Tags: android, file-upload, android-asynctask, android-service, androidhttpclient

I am looking for a way of a good working Upload Service to handle multiple upload requests. The aim should be to display a notification with the actual progress of all the uploads together.

Since now I got it working with calling an AsyncTask for every request, but that way I am not getting one notification for all of them, only one for each.

I read about using Services, but could not find anything about getting a Service (could also be an IntentService) handling more than one request. Just to point it out again: The user should be able to start an upload at any time and should be able to "add" a new upload at any time, but the uploads should run in the background, because what is going to be uploaded are images of variable sizes, means that they could become quite big. Also important is the ability of adding custom String entities like marked in the code as "additional...", ...

Here the actual code of my AsyncTask:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.StringBody;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder;
import android.util.Log;

public class ImageUploader extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

    private Context context;
    private String name = null;
    private String filePath = null;

    private NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
    private Builder mBuilder;

    public void setContext(Context context, String name){
        this.context = context;
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();   

        mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
        mBuilder.setContentTitle(name)
                .setContentText("Image is being uploaded")
                .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_upload);
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        mBuilder.setProgress(100, progress[0], false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        super.onProgressUpdate(progress);
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        filePath = params[0];           
        return uploadFile();
    }

    private String uploadFile() {
        String responseString = null;

        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(SERVER_PHP_URL);

        httpclient.getCredentialsProvider().setCredentials(new AuthScope(SERVER_HOST, AuthScope.ANY_PORT), new UsernamePasswordCredentials(SERVER_USER, SERVER_PASSWORD));

        try {
            AndroidMultiPartEntity entity = new AndroidMultiPartEntity(
                    new ProgressListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void transferred(long num) {
                            publishProgress((int) ((num / (float) totalSize) * 100));
                        }
                    });

            File sourceFile = new File(filePath);

            entity.addPart("image", new FileBody(sourceFile));

            entity.addPart("additional...", new StringBody("anything"));
            entity.addPart("additional2...", new StringBody("anything"));

            totalSize = entity.getContentLength();
            httppost.setEntity(entity);

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity r_entity = response.getEntity();

            int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                responseString = EntityUtils.toString(r_entity);
            } else {
                responseString = "Error occurred! Http Status Code: "
                        + statusCode;
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            responseString = e.toString();
        }

        return responseString;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        mBuilder.setContentText("Image uploaded successfully");
        mBuilder.setProgress(0, 0, false);
        mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
}
```

The customized MultipartEntity is as follows:

```
import java.io.FilterOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import org.apache.http.entity.mime.HttpMultipartMode;
import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntity;

public class AndroidMultiPartEntity extends MultipartEntity {

    private final ProgressListener listener;

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(final ProgressListener listener) {
        super();
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(final HttpMultipartMode mode,
            final ProgressListener listener) {
        super(mode);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    public AndroidMultiPartEntity(HttpMultipartMode mode, final String boundary, final Charset charset, final ProgressListener listener) {
        super(mode, boundary, charset);
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeTo(final OutputStream outstream) throws IOException {
        super.writeTo(new CountingOutputStream(outstream, this.listener));
    }

    public static interface ProgressListener {
        void transferred(long num);
    }

    public static class CountingOutputStream extends FilterOutputStream {

        private final ProgressListener listener;
        private long transferred;

        public CountingOutputStream(final OutputStream out,
                final ProgressListener listener) {
            super(out);
            this.listener = listener;
            this.transferred = 0;
        }

        public void write(byte[] b, int off, int len) throws IOException {
            out.write(b, off, len);
            this.transferred += len;
            this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
        }

        public void write(int b) throws IOException {
            out.write(b);
            this.transferred++;
            this.listener.transferred(this.transferred);
        }
    }
}
```

It would be very great if someone could bring me on the right track. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use some libraries for organize multiple tasks like goro(
https://github.com/stanfy/goro)

Also you can use new Thread in own separate service and some child of class BlockingQueue or class Handler inside the Thread. In my opinion this is more complex work.

Sory for my bad english